# Remove sum() in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove `sum()` from a query using regex while keeping the content and other formulas.

For example,

```
sum(a) / nullif(sum(b)::numeric, 0)
```

becomes

```
a / nullif(b::numeric, 0)
```

If it's any easier, we can assume that `sum()` will always be the inner formula, i.e. `sum(nullif(b,0))` won't happen.

Comment: regex is for string manipulation, not formula manipulation.

Comment: Have your tried anything? In your two examples this would work, https://regex101.com/r/8UVmbC/1/. Something like `+(b/2)` inside that `sum()` though would break that.

Comment: You really need to build a parser to remove it. It is basically impossible to determine what ) is the closing one.

Comment: Can you show the code you have, and where the problem is you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is regular expression that replace `sum` with his inner parameter:

```
"sum(a) / nullif(sum(b)::numeric, 0)".replace(/sum\((.*?)\)/g, '$1')
"a / nullif(b::numeric, 0)"
```

Comment: @epascarello OP has stated that functions won't be nested within `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed regexp which i came up with.

```
var inputString = "sum(a) / nullif(sum(b)::numeric, 0)"
var strToReplace = inputString.match(/sum\([\w]\)/g); /*Find all of type sum()*/
/*Convert get the variable to be replaced for sum(some word)*/
var varToReplace = strToReplace.map(function(item){  
    var x = item.replace(/sum\(/,''); x = x.replace(/\)/,'');return x;  })
/*Replace the string*/
strToReplace.forEach(function(item,index){
  var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(item));
  inputString = inputString.replace(re,varToReplace[index]);
})

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```